# Sklearn: are recall and precision swapped when are computed with precision_score and recall_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I'm using scikit-learn (version 0.22.1) for a machine learning application.

I'm using a Random Forest algorithm and I have some problems in evaluating the performance of the algorithm using precision and recall. I have the labels of my test set (Y_test) and the labels predicted using the Random Forest algorithm (Y_pred). Both data contains two labels (1 and 0)

In detail, I have this matrix:

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_true=Y_test, y_pred=Y_pred, labels=[1,0]))

[[78 20]
 [36 41]]
```

Consequently:

```
True Positive (tp) =  78
False Negative (fn) =  36
False Positive (fp) =  20
```

So:

```
PRECISION =  tp/(tp+fn) = 78/(78+36) = 0.7959183673469388
RECALL =  = tp/(tp+fp) = 78/(78+20) 0.6842105263157895
```

However, using this code:

```
precision = precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred, pos_label=1)
recall = recall_score(y_true=Y_test, y_pred=Y_pred, pos_label=1)

print("precision: ",precision)
print("recall: ",recall)
```

I get the following output:

```
recall:  0.7959183673469388
precision:  0.6842105263157895
```

It seems that the values are swapped when they are computed using the standard sklearn functions. 
Did I do something wrong?
Please, can you give me some advice?

Thanks,

Daniele

Comment: In your calculation you confused the formulas. For instance, precision is `tp/(tp+fp)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently calculating those values wrong. The correct calculations are;

Precision Calculation:

```
precision = tp/(tp+fp)
```

Recall Calculation:

```
recall = tp/(tp+fn)
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/precision-and-recall

Answer (score 0):

Formula is incorrect:

```
Precision: tp / tp+fp
Recall : tp/tp+fn
```